# DropDownList selected value lost on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback

On my page, i'm losing my dropdownlist's selected value on postback.

This is my aspx code.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProjectSearch.aspx.cs" Inherits="Site.Templates.ProjectSearch" MasterPageFile="~/Site/Templates/Framework/Base.master" 
    EnableViewState="true"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">

    <div>

            <ul>
                <li class="filter">
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="m_Filter" CssClass="form-control"/>
                </li>
                <li class="button">
                    <asp:LinkButton class="button-dark-orange" ID="m_search" runat="server" OnClick="m_search_click" >
                        Click
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </li>

            </ul>
    </div>
```

And in my code-behind there's nothing  other than button click.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDropdown();
        }
    }

    public void BindDropdown()
    {
        try
        {
            List<int> ds = Filter.GetData()
            m_filter.DataSource = ds;
            m_Filter.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected void m_search_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(m_Filter.SelectedIndex);
    }
```

It always writes 0. Any help?

Comment: it is normal that value will gone after postback, store in session or viewstate to retain the value

Comment: use `UpdatePanel` and put this `DropDownList` and `LinkButton` inside it.

Comment: i have div and li tags on this aspx. and update panel doesn't support this

Comment: Also, I have set enableviewstate of page and control to true.

Comment: The previous comments are somewhat unhelpful and in the case of the first one, just plain wrong.  Are you selecting something from the dropdown list prior to clicking the button?

Comment: Your code is absolutely correct, you should look for the problem elsewhere or post your complete code to providing a better help.

Comment: Yes, The code is absolutely correct, code you please edit your question and post complete code?

Answer (score -1):

only add  few things

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="m_Filter" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

write belove code in code behind file

```
        ddlproduct.DataSource = your method;
        ddlproduct.DataTextField = "text";
        ddlproduct.DataValueField = "value";
        ddlproduct.DataBind();
```

Comment: ddlproduct replace with your dropdownlist  id